# Ubuntu on rMBP, bootloader location

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, bootloader, macbook-pro, location

I'm getting ready to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 on my Macbook Pro. My setup is as follows:

Mac OSX and Windows-Bootcamp on the internal SSD

Ubuntu 13.04 on an external SSD hooked up through Thunderbolt

Currently I use rEFInd on a thumb drive to load Ubuntu. I'd like to take that out of the equation, but I don't want to install rEFInd on my Mac's internal drive. I know there has to be a way do make this work. I have an Ubuntu LiveUSB (made with Unetbootin) that works without rEFInd and loads the same way I would boot into Bootcamp. I'm just not sure where I should install the bootloader (EFI partition, right at the root of the drive, or on my system root partition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel like an idiot. I found the solution myself, I just installed rEFInd to the root of the SSD that Ubuntu resides on. Presto, it works. It worked for the USB 3.0 thumb drive I had as well. I'm not sure if it matters, but they are both formatted as GPT.

Comment: If you really want to do this without refind, you can create a standalone grub file and place it in a folder on your mac's /EFI partition. This would let you use the built in Mac Bootloader to load Ubuntu.

Comment: https://github.com/pandeiro/arch-on-air I know this guide is for arch on a macbook air, but steps 11-15 give a general idea of what you'd have to do to get this working. You'd have to adjust the kernel option to your system's needs.